# MYSQL get people who watched all football matches

Tags: mysql

```
fan(*IDfan*,name,surname)
match(*IDmatch*, type_of_competition, teamA, teamB, date, scoreA, scoreB)
booking(*IDfan,IDmatch*,price)...
 *name* : name is the primary key `
```

ex.

fan:

```
IDfan     Name   Surname
---------------------
1     | A      |A
2     | B      |B
3     | C      |C
```

match:

```
IDmatch   type        teamA    teamB         date...
----------------------------------------------------
1     | champions |Juve     |Barcellona |01/10/17
2     | league    |Milan    |Real       |02/11/17
3     | TIM cup   |Inter    |Napoli     |03/12/17
```

booking:

```
IDfan     IDmatch   price
---------------------
1     | 1      |5
1     | 2      |6
1     | 3      |7
2     |1       |8
2     |1       |8
2     |1       |8
3     |2       |5
3     |3       |10
```

Good morning, I can't realize how to select fans that watched all matches taking into account that a fan can buy more ticket for one competition. For example the result of the script applied to the database above must be:

IDfan     Name   Surname

---

```
1     | A      |A
```

Comment: Name is the primary key? I guess there are worse ideas, but I can't think of one.

Comment: Add the query you've tried out and is not working!

Comment: Or, better still, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited**

In `booking` table, it's weird that same-value rows appear three times.

```
IDfan     IDmatch   price
---------------------
2     |1       |8
2     |1       |8
2     |1       |8
```

Assume the three-times-appear is not wrong, 
this will be the right answer(not tested).

```
SELECT fan.*
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT IDfan, IDmatch
    FROM booking) AS distinct_booking
JOIN fan ON distinct_booking.IDfan = fan.IDfan
GROUP BY fan.IDfan, fan.Name, fan.Surname
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM match)
;
```

On the other hand, assume `booking` table has a unique constraint of `IDfan` and `IDmatch`, the three-times-appear is wrong,
Try this. tested and works

```
SELECT fan.*
FROM booking
JOIN fan ON booking.IDfan = fan.IDfan
GROUP BY fan.IDfan, fan.Name, fan.Surname
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM match)
;
```

For mysql, this will also work(tested)

```
SELECT fan.*
FROM booking
JOIN fan ON booking.IDfan = fan.IDfan
GROUP BY fan.IDfan
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM match)
;
```

--

Explanation for this comment.

> Can you explain me why you did this: GROUP BY fan.IDfan, fan.Name, fan.Surname ?

Some databases have a rule: columns in `SELECT` have to be in `GROUP BY` clause.

To get IDfan Name Surname, I wrote `GROUP BY fan.IDfan, fan.Name, fan.Surname`
But mysql is not the case, if primary key is in `GROUP BY`, it's just ok.

So, I read your question again and I realize you use mysql, then this will also work in mysql.

```
SELECT fan.*
FROM booking
JOIN fan ON booking.IDfan = fan.IDfan
GROUP BY fan.IDfan
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM match)
;
```

Comment: have you tested this code!

Comment: Can you explain me why you did this: GROUP BY fan.IDfan, fan.Name, fan.Surname ? It works anyway thanks

Comment: Sorry I haven't tested this query.

Comment: I have added explanation for `GROUP BY fan.IDfan, fan.Name, fan.Surname` in the post.

Comment: Also the second script works fine. Thanks so much for your help

Comment: @noymer the query is returning fan id 1 & 2, and as per the table booking detail, only fan 1 has watched the entire 3 matches...Am I right? please clear me.

Comment: @ArifMustafa Oh, you are right...
I assumed *booking table has a unique constraint of IDfan and IDmatch.*, but reading the question, it's not true for IDfan 2 data.

Comment: I added a new query, which takes consideration of `booking` table IDfan=2.

Comment: still if, you add match id's 2 & 3 watched by fan 2 in booking table, you query is now returning only fan 1 details.

Comment: @ArifMustafa 
You mean inserting `booking` table (IDfan, IDmatch, price) = (2, 2, 10), (2, 3, 11), and run the query `SELECT fan.*
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT IDfan, IDmatch
    FROM booking) ...`  the result is only fan 1 ?


Hmm, really? By `SELECT DISTINCT IDfan, IDmatch
    FROM booking`, this subquery result has (IDfan, IDmatch) = (2, 1), (2, 2),  (2, 3) I guess.

Comment: Actually the OP had a bad booking table, with repeated booked values for same match by fan id 2, so the query `select f.idfan, f.name, f.surname from booking b join fan f on b.idfan = f.idfan group by f.idfan having count(*) = (select count(*) from matchdet);` is good.

Comment: I agree with `a bad booking table`. I edited the post and write about it.